# Host DBpedia locally for categories

Tags: php, dbpedia

I've noticed you can download whole data dumps of DBpedia data, but I'm not sure how to get to it from my PHP application.  At the moment, I need to access category information which I am currently doing remotely through URLs like 
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Cities_in_England, but the site is slow and sometimes offline.  Is there any way of hosting DBpedia locally in a similar way?  I'm using PHP, is there perhaps a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can already run remote SPARQL queries from PHP, then if you can host the data on a SPARQL endpoint locally, you can use the same PHP code to query the local endpoint.  I don't know of any PHP based SPARQL endpoints (I'm not much of a PHP'er), but the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608265/querying-open-data-communities-data-with-sparql/16610663#16610663) describes how you can set a RDF store using Jena's TDB, and Jena's Fuseki can use that store for a SPARQL endpoint (just by adding a `--loc=DIR` to the command line;  see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17012988/1281433)).

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this link for setting up a virtuso triple store [Setting up Virtuso Triple store](http://joernhees.de/blog/2014/04/23/setting-up-a-local-dbpedia-3-9-mirror-with-virtuoso-7/)

By starting running virtuso server and adding files to it. You can have the data locally at a local sparql endpoint which you can query with the help of SPARQL.